# PHP DOM to get td class text

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am a complete newbie to DOM, please bear with me.
I am trying to get the content of one specific , on a web page, where citations are, the [webpage is:](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=rqzxwVsAAAAJ&hl=en)

and the td tag is:

```
<td class="gsc_rsb_std">7679</td>
```

I’m trying to get Just the number in this td tag (7679).
I tried using the DOM functions in the PHP core, but I couldnt figure out how to get the class. So then I tried using "[simple_html_Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)"
but I still cant seem to get it right. I get no errors in my server logs, and no results from my script. Im not sure what im doing wrong. 
 here is my script:

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$file = "https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=rqzxwVsAAAAJ&hl=en";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($file);

foreach($html->find('td[class="gsc_rsb_std"]') as $div){
    echo $div;
    echo "<br/>". $div->nodeName. ": ";
}

?>
```

Perhaps what im doing wrong will be more obvious to someone else.
How can I get the value between the tag `<td class="gsc_rsb_std"> </td>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($html->find('td[class="gsc_rsb_std"]') as $div){
    echo $div->innertext;
}
```

Echoing the inner text of that element e.g. the `7679`

#### Additionally,

`$html->load($file);`

should be

`$html->load_file($file);`

As otherwise it just treats the url as the html.